# JHipster - How to generate Entity with a field as List of String?

Tags: jhipster, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I'm using jhipster-generator 4.14.5 and im trying to generate an Entity with a field **Persons**. But Persons is a List of String `List<String> Persons`.

How can i achieve it in JHipster. I tried to generate a simple field as String, then i changed the POJO like this :

```
@ElementCollection
@Column(name="persons")
List<String> persons;
```

The domain.json containing the whole table remain not touched.

I tried to run the application, after running liquibase:diff, without success. How can i fix it?

Comment: Is person another entiy or not?

Comment: This isn't possible by default, if you want it generated then you need to add a OneToMany relationship to a Person entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the generator entity to create a relationship : 
Create an entity Person (maybe with only the "name", but more fields will soon be needed. Like "active", some dates ...)

.jhipster/[YourEntity].json should contain :

```
"fields": [
    {
        "fieldName": "xxx",
        "fieldType": "Integer"
    }
],
"relationships": [
    {
        "relationshipName": "person",
        "otherEntityName": "person",
        "relationshipType": "one-to-many",
        "relationshipValidateRules": [
            "required"
        ],
        "otherEntityField": "name"
    }
],
```

don't forget to commit before using the generator. Maybe you will need multiple executions to get it right.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Actually i don't want a List<Person> but a list of String. But like Jon Rudell said it's impossible per default right now. But i will accept your answer as a workaround.